# Creating a schematron to flag latinisms (etc, i.e, e.g) but its also flagging words with those letters in them

Tags: xml, schematron, oxygenxml

I have a schematron created to flag latinisms in a topic. It works a little too well. It's also flagging words that have that combination of letters in them. For example, it needs to flag "etc" but it is also flagging "k**etc**hup" because k**etc**hup has "etc" in the middle. I don't know what to change in my code to make it so it only flags the actual latinism and not other words.

Here is my code so far:

```
<sch:schema xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"
queryBinding="xslt2">
   <sch:let name="words" value="' i.e, etc., e.g., vs, et al, circa'"/>
    <sch:let name="wordsToMatch" value="replace($words, ',', '|')"/>
    <sch:pattern id = "LatinismsCheck">
    <sch:rule context="text()">
        <sch:report test="matches(., $wordsToMatch)" role="warn">
            The following words should not be added in the topic:
            <sch:value-of select="$words"/>
           </sch:report>
        </sch:rule>
    </sch:pattern>
</sch:schema>
```

Comment: StackOverflow exists to help you with coding problems. It's not the right place to ask questions about algorithms, application design, or natural language processing. If you know what you want your program to do, it's fine to ask here. If you don't, you need to ask somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can mark in the regular expression the word boundary with '\b'. Something like this:

```
<sch:schema xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"
queryBinding="xslt2" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<sch:let name="words" value="'i.e.,etc.,e.g.'"/>
<sch:let name="wordsToMatch">
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($words,',')">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('(\b', normalize-space(.), ')')"/>
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
            <xsl:value-of select="'|'"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</sch:let>

<sch:pattern>
    <sch:rule context="text()">
        <sch:report test="matches(., string($wordsToMatch), ';j')" role="warn">
            The following words should not be added in the topic: <sch:value-of select="$words"/>
        </sch:report>
    </sch:rule>
</sch:pattern></sch:schema>
```